I encounted a graph error while trying to fix somethings at the backend
backend-1   | GraphError
backend-1   |     at new GraphError (/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphError.js:34:28)
backend-1   |     at Function. (/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphErrorHandler.js:97:30)
backend-1   |     at step (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:195:27)
backend-1   |     at Object.next (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:176:57)
backend-1   |     at /app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:169:75
backend-1   |     at new Promise ()
backend-1   |     at Object.__awaiter (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:165:16)
backend-1   |     at GraphErrorHandler.getError (/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphErrorHandler.js:87:24)
backend-1   |     at GraphRequest. (/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphRequest.js:315:84)
backend-1   |     at step (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:195:27) {
backend-1   |   statusCode: 403,
backend-1   |   code: null,
backend-1   |   requestId: null,
backend-1   |   date: 2024-11-27T10:18:11.306Z,
backend-1   |   body: '403 FORBIDDEN'
backend-1   | }
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  //check if password match
  // retlogurn jwt token
  //bcrpt compare password
  const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const clientId = '...';
  const clientSecret = '...';
  const tenantId = '...';
  const excelFileId =
    'https://vincil.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/reservoir/_layouts/15/Doc2.aspx?action=edit&sourcedoc=%7Bca3eb7d8-98e3-4e33-ba33-a4fb77d0cfc3%7D&wdOrigin=TEAMS-WEB.teamsSdk_ns.rwc&wdExp=TEAMS-TREATMENT&wdhostclicktime=1732623964116&web=1';

  const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId,
    clientId,
    clientSecret
  );

  async function getAccessToken() {
    const tokenResponse = await credential.getToken(
      'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    );
    console.log(tokenResponse);
    return tokenResponse.token;
  }

  async `function` getGraphClient() {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    return Client.init({
      authProvider: (done) => {
        done(null, accessToken);
      },
    });
  }`enter code here`

  async function downloadExcelFile() {
    const client = await getGraphClient();
    const fileDownloadPath = excelFileId;
    const fileData = await client.api(fileDownloadPath).get();
    const savePath = path.join(_dirname, 'uploads', 'teams-file.xlsx');
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(savePath);

    fileData.pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('finish', () => {
      console.log('Excel file saved successfully');
    });
  }

  downloadExcelFile().catch(console.error);

  async function comparePasswords(plaintextPassword, hashedPassword) {
    try {
      return await bcrypt.compare(plaintextPassword, hashedPassword);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error comparing passwords:', error);
      return false;
    }
  }

  try {
    User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
    }).then(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const isMatch = await comparePasswords(
          req.body.password.toString(),
          user.password.toString()
        );
        console.log(isMatch);

        if (isMatch) {
          res.json({
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            token: generateToken(user.id),
          });
          // res.send(null);
        } else {
          res.status(400).json({ invalidCredentials: 'Invalid Credentials' });
        }
      } else {
        res.send(null);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});



Can you paste the API permissions blade screenshot?

@Rukmini i have added API Permissions blade screenshot

You have to grant application type API permissions as you are making use of ClientSecretCredential flow

Grant admin consent to Files.Read.All application type API permission to resolve the error

Posted the answer, Please check the below:)


Note that: ClientSecretCredential supports Application type API permissions only.

The error 403 usually occurs if the access token does not contain the required API permissions to call the API.
Hence to resolve the error, as you are making use of ClientSecretCredential grant Application type API permissions not delegated.
Grant Files.ReadWrite.All application type API permission:

For sample, I generated access token by using below parameters:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: ClientID
client_secret: TenantASecret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


To get the ItemID run the below query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/drive/root/children


To download the excel make use of below query as the query you are using is invalid:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/drive/items/ItemID


When you click on @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl the excel file will be downloaded successfully.
For JavaScript, make use of below code:
const options = {
authProvider,
};
const client = Client.init(options);
let driveItem = await client.api('/sites/SiteID/drive/items/ItemID/content')
.get();

Sample code:
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { Client } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

const clientId = 'your-client-id';
const clientSecret = 'your-client-secret';
const tenantId = 'your-tenant-id';

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

const options = {
  authProvider: (done) => {
    credential.getToken('https://graph.microsoft.com/.default').then((tokenResponse) => {
      done(null, tokenResponse.token);
    }).catch((err) => {
      done(err, null);
    });
  },
};

const client = Client.init(options);

async function downloadFile() {
  try {
    const siteId = 'SiteID';
    const fileId = 'ItemID';
    const fileDownloadPath = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/drive/items/${fileId}/content`;

    const fileStream = await client.api(fileDownloadPath).get();
    const savePath = path.join(__dirname, 'downloads', 'downloaded-file.xlsx');
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(savePath);

    fileStream.pipe(writeStream);

    writeStream.on('finish', () => {
      console.log('File downloaded and saved successfully!');
    });

    writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error saving file:', err);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading the file:', error);
  }
}

downloadFile().catch(console.error);

Reference:
Download driveItem content - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
